# UnityEditor.Undo in runtime

Tags: unity3d-editor

I want to know what such a UnityEditor.Undo Destroy, AddComponent functions, it operates correctly even on the device runtime.

For example the following code works fine in the editor on the PC. I wonder if this be the same result in the devices.

```
public void Click()
 {
     Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>());
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Undo` class is from the `UnityEditor` namespace. This means that it won't work on any device or build. The only reason it is working now is because you are running it in the Editor.

Any Unity API that starts with `UnityEditor` will **never** work on any device or build. It is designed to allow programmers make a custom Editor plugin which runs on the Editor **only**.

Although, you can [implement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBIhXLtkvCw) your own Undo class by using [Stack](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stack).